# How to look at items in the inventory?

Tags: tex-murphy-2

In Tex Murphy 2 Martian Memorandum, once I pick something up, I seem to be unable to look at the item any longer.

At Alexis' home I picked up the piece of paper to the left side of the bed. I can no longer read it.

[image]

Is there any way to look at things after picking them up? If not, what was written on it?

Comment: Seems like I had a save game right before. The piece of paper says "TMS". Doesn't answer the question though ...